# Logical Error when calculating mean square error

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
a=imread('pic1.jpg');
b=0.25*a;
c=4.0*b;
figure;
imshow(c);
MSE = reshape(mean(mean(((a) - (c)).^2,2),1),[1,3])
```

Code works fine without any errors. Size of a is 256*256*3 RGB type. However,
There are 2 issues :

1. Now logically, the MSE should have been zero for RGB bands since multiplying the result c with 4.0 should reverse the operation. But MSE is coming out to be `1.1361    1.2780    1.2902` The same is observed when testing with `b=0.27.*a`; then `c=3.703703704.*b`;
2. In MSE formula, on removing double data type , the error minimises to `0.5346    0.6132    0.6275`

Can anyone explain it lucidly why this is happening and what is the remedy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the data type of your variable a. It is probably a uint8, which means b also becomes uint8 containing rounded values - in other words you loose two bits of information per pixel.

You mention "double data type", but I don't see where you use it in your code.

If you started with
a=double(imread('pix1.jpg'));
then your MSE should nearly zero (I'd expect it to be on the order of 256*256*3*eps (i.e. rounding error)).

Comment: "You mention "double data type", but I don't see where you use it in your code." If I am working with uint8, then in MSE formula if I put MSE = reshape(mean(mean((double(a) - double(c)).^2,2),1),[1,3]), then the error values are different. This was observed at the time I posted the query(when a was of uint8 type) and however does not hold anymore after you explanation. Thank you.